# Customize CSS for selectedItem in a ComboBox in ExtJs

Tags: css, extjs, combobox, selecteditem

How can I customize CSS for selected items in a ComboBox? Pass "selectedItemCls" trough "listConfig" method doesn't work. Why?

Comment: post some code you tried

Answer (score 1):

You have to overload the .x-boundlist-selected class. For example, if you want the selected value in read and bold, you could do the follow:

```
.x-boundlist-selected {
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: red;
}​
```

Take a look at this working example: http://jsfiddle.net/lontivero/P9awz/1/

Update:

The selectedItemCls doesn´t not work because there is no way to change its value given it is assign in the InitComponent method:

```
me.selectedItemCls = baseCls + '-selected';
```

Then, the only way to change it is providing a value for baseCls. But if you do that, you will need to create all the family of css classes that combobox use.

Take a look at this working (even uncompleted) example: http://jsfiddle.net/P9awz/3/

This works as you want but the styles are not done.

Good luck.

Comment: Hi, it's not I'm looking for because it's overload all selected items of all combobox in my application. I want only customize the selected items of a specific combobox.